# When I mock my ASP.NET MVC controller, my ActionMethod returns no view. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, mocking, moq

In my simple `Index()` ActionMethod I reference the User.Identity property. So, I thought that I need to mock that.

So i create a some mock `HomeController` and use that in my unit test. When I do that, the `ActionMethod` returns null as the view. When I replace the mock'd controller with a concrete instance (and of course comment out any reference to `User.Identity`) then the correct view is returned.

eg.

```
// Arrange.
var homeController = Mock<HomeController>(..);
homeController.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(new GenericPrincipal(..));

// Act.
var result = homeController.Index();

// Assert.
Assert.IsNotNull(result); // This fails here. result is NULL.
```

but when I do this (and comment out any `User` reference), it works...

```
// Arrange.
var homeController = new HomeController(..);

// Act.
var result = homeController.Index();

// Assert.
Assert.IsNotNull(result); // Tick!
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Which mocking library are you using?

Comment: Also, what specifically are you testing for here? Whether the mocking library works?

Comment: I'm using Moq and i'm testing some results that come back in the view. I'm not testing the moq library itself. I think the issue is because the mock controller has no context and request stuff, which the ViewEngine needs?

Comment: Also added moq as a tag.

Comment: What I meant was, you're mocking the controller, which would mean that the controller you're calling `.Index()` on is a mock, which makes no sense. That mock would never do anything, except if you explicitly tell it to do stuff or return stuff. In other words, you're testing a mock.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - yep! completely agreed! I constantly get messed up with testing something i've mocked, which is SO wrong *blush*. mocks are there to -help- my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be mocking a HttpContext for the controller to work with. [**I provided one on another answer that you could use**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476041/nunit-testing-mvc-site/7476153#7476153). As [Steve Rowbotham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874574/when-i-mock-my-asp-net-mvc-controller-my-actionmethod-returns-no-view-why/7874787#7874787) says, you should be mocking the dependencies of the system under test (i.e. the dependencies of the controller) and not mocking the system under test itself; you want to test the real version of the controller not a mock :)

Using the `HttpContextBase` class from the link, you would simply do the following in your test

```
var controllerToTest = new HomeController();
var context = new MockHttpContextBase(controllerToTest);

// do stuff that you want to test e.g. something goes into session

Assert.IsTrue(context.HttpContext.Session.Count > 0);
```

You may go a step further and create Setup and TearDown methods to set the controller up with a mocked context.

Answer (score 3):

There are some strange things in your unit test. You are unit testing a controller and yet you are mocking the creation of the object under test: `var homeController = Mock<HomeController>(..);` which is incorrect.

Here's the correct way to inject a mocked user into a controller that you are willing to unit test:

```
// arrange
var sut = new HomeController();
var user = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("foo"), null);
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
httpContext.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(user);
var context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData()), sut);
sut.ControllerContext = context;

// act
var actual = sut.Index();

// assert
...
```

Comment: Cheers! I'll give this ago. As an aside... Hmm.. this reminds me of some code I saw somewhere.... where was it.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, there are [gazillions of places](http://www.google.com/search?s?hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=35&gs_id=3l&xhr=t&q=moq%20asp.net%20mvc%20moq%20user%20controller&pq=moq+asp.net+mvc+moq+user+controller&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&safe=active&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&biw=1680&bih=945&ech=2&psi=K0ilTsrKCYTqOYLE6fwE.1319454763487.4&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&ei=M0ilTue3J9CXOsfX_L4N) over the internet where you find this code. Here's an example: http://www.codethinked.com/simplified-aspnet-mvc-controller-testing-with-moq

Comment: I found it last night after I left work. It was from NerdDinner - part 12 : http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part12.htm :) :)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this looks like a very strange test because you're mocking the system under test (SUT), in other words the `HomeController`. Usually one would mock the dependencies of the SUT, set the expectations on the mock and inject the mock into the SUT to confirm that it is properly interacting with its dependencies.

When you create a mock of the `HomeController`, Moq is creating a class that inherits from HomeController and overrides the virtual method `Index`. So when you call `Index` on the mock you're not calling the implementation of `Index` you've defined in the `HomeController` class but the overridden one. Since you've not explicitly `Setup` the method on the mock it will return the default value, in this case `null`.

In your second test you're calling the actual implementation of `Index` because you're constructing an actual instance of the `HomeController` class. If you call `GetType()` on the instance of the mock object then you'll see that it's an instance of a proxy that derives from `HomeController` which intercepts calls to the publicly defined, overridable methods on the base class (which is a large part of the purpose of a mock object).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your Index method is probably virtual, which causes Moq to replace that function with a mocked function. In order to prevent that, you need to set the CallBase property on the mock.

However, I agree with the other replies that you should not be mocking your controller, but you should mock your dependency.

(an even simpler method is to create a specialized model binder that can fetch the principal from the HttpContext, then you can just pass the principal as input parameter to your method)